# Unable to convert dates from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, date

I have developed a C# application to read data from Excel files. There are few dates as well which are in the format **"dd/MM/yyyy"** and I am able to convert them into `DateTime` objects. However, when I put this same code on the Web server, it reads the Excel date in format **"MM/dd/yyyy"**. I have checked the locale settings on the server and it's same as my local machine which is **"en-AU"**. Below is the function which converts the date:

```
private DateTime? GetDate(string value)
    {
        if (value.Contains('/') || value.Contains('-'))
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime();

            string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy",
                    "dd/MM/yy", "dd/M/yy", "d/M/yy", "d/MM/yy", '"d-MMM-yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "d-MMM-yy", "dd-MMM-yy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"};

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                double add = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(add);

                return date;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using `OleDBDataAdapter` to read the Excel file into a `DataTable` object. The function  parses all possible date formats, however it always returns null.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with `new CultureInfo("en-AU")`.